# factorygirl save data before test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've a problem with FactoryGirl. I created a separate file, where do:

```
shared_context 'basic organization structure' do
  subject(:organization)  { FactoryGirl.create_list(:organization, 2) }
end
```

and connect it to the test like include_context. When I run the tests, I don't see data in the test database. They only appear when called explicitly in the tests. 
How do I make sure that before the test data stored in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed `let` and `subject`. `subject` is not for representing variable/method, so it can't works like an assignment.

Instead, use `let` to represent the variable(actually it is a method), and subject it later.

```
shared_context 'basic organization structure' do
  let(:organization)  { FactoryGirl.create_list(:organization, 2) }
  subject {organization} # Note: use method name here, not symbol
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you're using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to clean the database between tests? If so you have 2 choices: Either (a) if you want the organization list to persist across your test suite add it to a seed.rb file and set the `database_cleaner` strategy to `:transaction` or (b) use a `before(:each) do` block in each test to create the organisation list explicitly before each test in the database.

(There's little point looking at the DB when the test runs because `database_cleaner` wipes the DB so fast it's unlikely you'll be able to see the records before they're deleted.)